# Kubernetes job vs pod in containerCreating state

Tags: kubernetes, job-scheduling, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to force a pod that is stuck on `containerCreating` state (for valid reasons like can't mount an inaccessible NFS, etc.) to move to a failed state after a specific amount of time.

I have Kubernetes `jobs` that I'm running through a Jenkins pipeline. I'm using the job state (`type: completed|failed`) to determine the outcome and then I gather the results of the jobs (`kubectl get pods` + `kubectl logs`). It works well as long as the pods go into a known failed state like `ContainerCannotRun` or `Backofflimit` and therefore the `job` state goes to `failed`.

Where the problem arises is when a pod goes into `containerCreating` state and stays that way. Then, the job state stays `active` and will never change. Is there a way, in the `job` manifest to put something to force a pod that's in `containerCreating` state to move to a failed state after a certain amount of time?

Example:
**pod status**

```
    - image: myimage
      imageID: ""
      lastState: {}
      name: primary
      ready: false
      restartCount: 0
      state:
        waiting:
          reason: ContainerCreating
    hostIP: x.y.z.y
    phase: Pending
    qosClass: BestEffort
    startTime: "2020-05-06T17:09:58Z"
```

**job status**

```
    active: 1
    startTime: "2020-05-06T17:09:58Z"
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup) use `activeDeadlineSeconds` or `backoffLimit`

The `activeDeadlineSeconds` applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches `activeDeadlineSeconds`, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded.

Once `backoffLimit` has been reached the Job will be marked as failed and any running Pods will be terminated.

Note that a Job’s `activeDeadlineSeconds` takes precedence over its `backoffLimit`. Therefore, a Job that is retrying one or more failed Pods will not deploy additional Pods once it reaches the time limit specified by `activeDeadlineSeconds`, even if the `backoffLimit` is not yet reached.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-timeout
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. The pod does not fail, it is in `containerCreating` state. What you're suggesting is what I already use for pods that do fail in `CrashbackLoopOff` or `ContainerCannotRun` states.

Comment: so what is actually keeping the pod in containerCreating?

Comment: Somebody inputting the wrong NFS remote path when executing the job. I know how to fix the problem, I just need to automate the destruction of the job when a pod gets stuck in this state. I was hoping there was a way to force a pod in `containerCreating` state to fail after X minutes instead of me having to script around it.

Comment: This does work - you can define the `activeDeadlineSeconds` at both the `job.spec` and `pod.spec` levels.  For your requirements, define it in job spec and it will fail the job if the job is not failed or completed after that time period (regardless of what state the pods are in)